# I am getting this error "Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs"

Tags: r

I am getting this error in R and this is the code that I am using

tweets.words <- Text.data %>%
mutate(linenumber = row_number()) %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text)

Comment: I can't see the problem; if possible, it might help if you could edit your question to include the output from `dput(head(Text.data))` and also maybe the output from `str(Text.data)`

Comment: You might have `plyr` loaded in your environment which is masking the `mutate` function. Try with `tweets.words <- Text.data %>% dplyr::mutate(linenumber = row_number()) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)`